# Grouping types based on mime type property inside object: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am having the following object that is being sent as an object to a function,

```
const mimeTypes = {
  image: [".svg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"],
  application: [".pdf", ".zip"],
  text: [".txt", ".csv"]
};
```

I need to transform the above object into another object, based on mime type,
The result should look like

```
const result = {
  "image/*": [".svg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"],
  "application/zip": [".zip"],
  "application/pdf": [".pdf"],
  "text/*": [".txt", ".csv"]
};
```

Here application level types are handled with their mime types, rest of the types are generic ones and follow `image/*` or `text/*`

How do I transform this? I am a beginner to this

```
function transform(obj){
   let res = {};
   for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.key === 'image') {
      res["image/*"] = obj.image;
    }
    if (obj.key === 'text') {
      res["text/*"] = obj.text;
    }
   }
   return res;
}
```

When just  `const input = { text: [".txt", ".csv"]`} is passed, the resultant object should only have `text` related object. In this case the result should have text related object like
`const result = { "image/*":text: [".txt", ".csv"] };`

Is there a more simpler and compact version of this?

Comment: `obj.key == 'image'` should be `key == 'image'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no `obj.key`, you just want to compare the variable `key`.

When the key isn't `image` or `text`, you need to loop over all the values, creating the corresponding `application/XXX` keys in the result.

```js
const mimeTypes = {
  image: [".svg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"],
  application: [".pdf", ".zip"],
  text: [".txt", ".csv"]
};

function transform(obj) {
  let res = {};
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, extensions]) => {
    if (key === 'image') {
      res["image/*"] = extensions;
    } else if (key === 'text') {
      res["text/*"] = extensions;
    } else {
      extensions.forEach(val => res[`application/${val.substring(1)}`] = [val]);
    }
  });
  return res;
}


console.log(transform(mimeTypes));
```

Comment: thanks so much. Not sure if this makes sense, can this be solved using `reduce` using empty object as initial value?

Comment: Yes, it can. I'm not a big fan of that use of `reduce()`, I don't think it's any easier to read than using the explicit `res` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're being unnecessarily clever here.  Consider using the 48M+/week downloaded library called [mime-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types).

The idea is just to have a simple map

```
{ 
  ".svg": "image/svg",
  ".png": "image/png",
  /* etc. */
}
```

and spell them all out manually.  The library does this for you.

`mime.lookup(".md")` will be `text/markdown` - a simple transformation that is already beyond the complexity of your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Array.prototype.reduce` function along with computed property names.

```js
const mimeTypes = {
  image: [".svg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg"],
  application: [".pdf", ".zip"],
  text: [".txt", ".csv"]
};

function transform(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, extensions]) => {
    if (key === 'image') {
      return {...acc, "image/*": extensions};
    } else if (key === 'text') {
      return {...acc, "text/*": extensions};
    }
    
    return {...acc, ...extensions.reduce((iacc, ext) => ({...iacc, [`application/${ext.substring(1)}`]: [ext]}), {})};

  }, {});
}


console.log(transform(mimeTypes));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```